# change column wise to row wise in my PostgreSQL database query

Tags: postgresql

i need to change my query from column wise to row wise in postgressql

```
"select mu.unit_name,s.name,sum(cl.quantity),
sum(case when cl.measure_unit>0 then cl.measure_unit * cl.sale_price 
 else cl.quantity * cl.sale_price end) as value
from shop.currentledger cl ,
master.prd_product pp ,
master.master_division var,
master.store s,
master.master_unit mu 
where cl.product_code= pp.apco_code 
and pp.division=var.id
and var.vtype=s.id 
and cl.unit=mu.apco_unit_code group by s.name,mu.unit_name";
```

i tried it in my organisation

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.